# Horizon floating ip address

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I wonder if anyone knows why there is no panel for floating ip address in the Horizon dashboard?
[image]

here is my Horizon dashboard version:
3:18.3.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.4
I can create and assign using the openstack cli.

Comment: You also don't have the Routers panel. This makes me think that [enable_router](https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/configuration/settings.html#enable-router) may be set to False.

Comment: yes. that was the issue. thanks it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, the enable_router set to false. by enabling to true, it resolves the issue.